# Longest zig-zag subsequence in a string

Tags: python, zigzag

How can I optimize the below code that I have written for this problem? Can I get some suggestions?

Given an array of integer elements, find the length of the longest subsequence such that all elements are alternating. If a sequence {x1, x2, .. xn} is alternating sequence then its element satisfies one of the following relations:

```
x1 < x2 > x3 < x4 > x5 < …. xn
```

or

```
x1 > x2 < x3 > x4 < x5 > …. xn
```

**Input**:

```
8
10 22 9 33 49 50 31 60
```

where: First line represents the number of elements in the array.
Second line represents the array elements.

**Output**:

```
6
```

**Explanation**:

The subsequence `{10, 22, 9, 33, 31, 60}`  is in the format `x1 < x2 > x3 < x4 > x5 < x6` i.e. `{ 10 < 22 > 9 < 33 > 31 < 60 }` and it is the largest of this form and the length of this subsequence is `6`, hence the output `6`.

```
n = int(input())
L = []
for e in input().split():
    L.append(int(e))
count, i = 0, 0
flag = None
while i < (len(L) - 1):
    for j in range(i+1, len(L)):
        if count == 0 and flag is None:
            if (L[i] < L[j]):
                count+=1
                flag = 1
                i = j
                break
            elif (L[i] > L[j]):
                count+=1
                flag = 0
                i = j
                break
            else:
                i = j
        else:
            if (flag == 0) and (L[i] < L[j]):
                count+=1
                flag = 1
                i = j
                break
            elif (flag == 1) and (L[i] > L[j]):
                count+=1
                flag = 0
                i = j
                break
            else:
                i = j

print(count+1)
```

Comment: Why do you want to optimize it? Which time complexity do you have and which do you want to get?

Comment: @Olha I want to reduce the lines of code. I believe there are extra bits of code here which can be modified further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can iterate the list while keeping a reference to the previous node that did not contribute to the alternating pattern.

We start at setting the prev_node as the first element in the list.
The loop starts at index 1 and iterates till the end. For each value, it compares the value with prev_node. If it is of an alternating pattern, increment the max_lenght, and update prev_node.

```
LT = -1     # Less than
GT = 1      # Greater than

max_length = 1
prev_node = L[0]       # Begin at 0
prev_compare = 0
found = 0
for i in range(1, len(L)):
    if L[i] < prev_node:
        if prev_compare != LT:
            prev_compare = LT
            found = True
    elif L[i] > prev_node:
        if prev_compare != GT:
            prev_compare = GT
            found = True
    # If an alternating node is found
    if found:
        max_length += 1
        prev_node = L[i]
        found = False

print(max_length)
```

- Time complexity: **O(n)**, as it traverse the list only once.
- Space complexity: **O(1)**, as (additional) memory usage does not depend on input size.

---

### EDIT #1

From your comments, I assume you don't really care much about readability of code.

I have a short version (in terms of character count) of the same algorithm as above. The logic is basically the same, thus the performance is the same.

```
nodes = [L[0]]
prev_compare = -1
for e in L[1:]:
    if e != nodes[-1] and (e > nodes[-1]) != prev_compare:
        prev_compare = e > nodes[-1]
        nodes += [e]

print(len(nodes))
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use generators to perform the following checks:

- whether for two consecutive numbers `x` and `y` it holds that `x < y`,
- whether two consecutive `<` comparisons, `c1` and `c2`, are alternating, i.e. `c1 != c2`.

Then you can find the longest sub-sequence for which the second check is `True`. Here we need to take into account that both checks consume one "length unit" from the original sequence, i.e. if we find that two consecutive `<` comparisons are alternating this will be indicated by a single `True` however it was generated by two comparisons. And these two comparisons in turn were generated by three consecutive numbers. So we can account for this by adding `2` to the final result.

Here's a code example:

```py
import itertools as it
from more_itertools import pairwise

numbers = [...]  # input goes here

less_than = (x < y for x, y in pairwise(numbers))
alternating = (x != y for x, y in pairwise(less_than))
lengths = (
    sum(1 for _ in g)  # length of sub-sequence
    for k, g in it.groupby(alternating)
    if k  # check if it's an alternating sub-sequence
)
result = max(lengths, default=-1) + 2
```

Comment: I wonder if this would work for a list of size _n_ containing same number.

Comment: @VINEETKUMAR In that case you need to add `default=-1` to `max`, see my updated answer.